# pydev does not recognize future annotations

Tags: eclipse, annotations, pydev

I am using eclipse 2020-09 with pydev 8.0.0 to develop python desktop applications.
The interpreter is python 3.8 and the python grammer is set to the same as interpreter.

If a class has a member method with one parameter of the same class type, it does not recognize it.
Instead, it gives me an "**Undefined variable: A**" error

```
class A:
    def non_self(self, a: A) -> bool:
        return self is not a
```

Adding the future import line

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

did not fix it.
I don't want to put the class name in a string, like

```
class A:
    def non_self(self, a: 'A') -> bool:
        return self is not a
```

What can I do?

Comment: If PyDev simply does not support that yet, I would simply accept it and wait for a version when they implement it, patiently, (or actively, by implementing and submitting it myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that it was fixed in PyDev version 8.1.0

Thank you @Fabio Zadrozny